# How do I move an email that I've already read to another folder in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I receive +/- 50 emails a day.  How do I mark them as read and responded to once finished in Outlook? I sort my emails as "unread" on top but many of the emails I have already read show up as unread. I am new to the Outlook program so I may be missing a common setting.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

To file an email, be in the Home Ribbon, and use the Move Command. Pull it down and file wherever you wish.  See the first Screen Shot below.

To control Read and Unread, be in the View Ribbon, and pull down Reading Pane Options.  See the second Screen Shot below. I mark an email Read after a few seconds. You should use whichever options help you.

To mark an Email Read or Unread, use the List of Emails (either Screen Shot).  Right click on the email and choose Read or Unread or other actions.

Good luck. Outlook is a very nice tool

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try your suggestions and apreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
How do I mark them as read and responded to once finished?
```

To achieve this, creating a custom quick step might could make things a little bit easier for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  I'll give it a shot!

Comment: You are welcome. Hope this can be useful to you.